# Как вставить ссылку на изображение в pictureBox | Windows Form?

Tags: c#

Как я могу вставить изображение, используя ссылку?
Вот мой тестовый код:

```
   private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Steve = textBox1.Text;
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.url($@"https://cravatar.eu/helmavatar/{ Steve }/190.png");
    }
```

Comment: [PictureBox.Load Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.load?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)

Comment: Не очень понятно в документации

Comment: Вы серьезно? `pictureBox1.Load(url)` - не очень понятно? Начните учить язык. На копировании примеров далеко не уехать.